# SSH command in Java/JSch giving exit code -1

Tags: java, unix, ssh, error-handling, jsch

I am checking file modified status of a server remotely using JSch in Java. apart from the output, i am also checking exit code.
While the test server is running fine and giving exit code as 0, the production server is throwing exit code -1. How do i get more details on this -1 and its meaning.

Here is my code, with sensitive areas removed.
How do I get more details on the last line `getExitStatus`.

```
JSch js=new JSch(); 
Session s = js.getSession(username, host, 22);
s.setPassword(password);

Properties ssconfig = new Properties();
ssconfig.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
s.setConfig(ssconfig);
s.connect();

Channel c = s.openChannel("exec");
ChannelExec ce = (ChannelExec) c;

ce.setCommand("cd <some file dir> && date && ls -ltr");
ce.setErrStream(System.err);

ce.connect();

/*
 * temporary test print
 */
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}

/*
 * end of temporary print
 */
ce.disconnect();
s.disconnect();

System.out.println("Exit code: " + ce.getExitStatus());

return ce.getExitStatus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getExitStatus`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus--) returns -1, when the exit code is not known yet.

You may need to wait for [`Channel.isClosed`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#isClosed--) before calling [`Channel.disconnect`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#disconnect--).

---

In your test environment, the connection or server may be quick enough to fill the exit status before you read it. While on production server it is not. A simple race condition.